# Regex pattern to remove duplicate value in a str

Tags: python, list, replace, duplicates

I need to remove the duplicate in a str and return a unique value using regex pattern.

```
Value = "['234.78','234.78']"
```

Expected result:

```
Value ="['234.78']"
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're working with formatted string data - you'd be better off using something like [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) instead if it's a Python-compatible data structure, rather than regular expressions. From there, you can use [the `list -> set -> list` methodology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists) to remove duplicates, then `repr()` to get the string representation back the way you prescribe:

```
import ast
value = "['234.78','234.78']"
value = list(set(ast.literal_eval(value)))
value = repr(value) # "['234.78']"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the data is *almost* JSON format, you could replace the single-quotes with double-quotes:

```py
import json

def dedupe_serialized_list(serialized_list: str):
    """
    Dedupe a serialized list of str values.

    :param str serialized_list: A serialized list of str values
    :return: a deduped list (re-serialized)
    :rtype: str
    """
    return str(list(set(json.loads(serialized_list.replace("'", '"')))))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(dedupe_serialized_list("['234.78','234.78']")) # ['234.78']
```

As a lambda:

```py
dedupe = lambda value: str(list(set(json.loads(value.replace("'", '"')))))
```

Answer (score -2):

Esqew's answer is a sensible approach.

If you're desperate to do it with regex, then the below code works:

```
import re
Value = "['234.78','234.78']"
Value=re.sub(r"('\d+\.\d+'),\1",r'\1',Value)
Value #"['234.78']
```

The matching pattern looks for a quote, ≥1 numbers, a decimal point and ≥1 numbers, a quote, a comma, then the number repeated.